# Как центрировать view относительно другого view?

Tags: android, android-layout

Можно ли горизонтально центрировать один view относительно другого, например, RatingBar под imageView?

Comment: обернуть обе вьюшки, к примеру, в `LinearLayout` и задать им `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: Все зависит от ситуации. Возможно нужен LinearLayout, возможно RelativeLayout. Уточните чего именно вы хотите добиться и в каком контексте, по тому как 2 вью можно по разному позиционировать относительно друг друга огромным количеством способов.

Comment: RatingBar размещается под ImageView. Мне нужно горизонтальное центрирование RatingBar относительно ImageView. Желательно без обертки.

Comment: без обертки, это либо на глаз центровать в `dp`, либо использовать `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Что значит "без обертки" - в любом случае на разметке присутствует контейнер, в котором помещаются `View`/ Так как способов отцентрировать два виджета очень много и зависят они от контейнера в котором находятся эти `View`, уточните свой вопрос - какие именно проблемы с центрированием, как именно нужно отцентрировать. Приложите разметку в которой у вас не получается это сделать. В текущем виде вопрос слишком общий и для ответа на него нужно гадать, что не приветствуется данным ресурсом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без контейнера не получится. Попробуйте это.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/iv_home"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"/>

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```